# Convert WebClient to XMLElement. VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, api

I have link to API.XML and need to convert its data to XmlElement for further iteration

My solution is:

```
dim wc as WebClient = new WebClient()
wc.DownloadFile("http://192.168.88.11:8088/api", "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\getxml.xml")
dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\getxml.xml")
dim x as XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
```

Is there better way without saving it to file?

Comment: You can make a Request and get the Xml String.   Then use doc.Parse(string) instead of doc.Load(filename)

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought:

```
Dim x As New XmlDocument()
x.Load("http://192.168.88.61:8088/api")
```